# How to modify week number starting in a specific day using fullcalendar plugin

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to start the week number from 1 when I specify a start date. Is it possible?

For example:
Week number usually starts at 1 on January first
I want my calendar to start week number at 1 from July 4/2016 and show weeks upto 1/December/2017.

Comment: post your code http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: explained the question in detail.